# Custom variables in TFS Release Management

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm using TFS 2017.1 Builds and Release feature.
In my release definition, I have a couple of release variables which I need to refer in my PowerShell task (execute on remote machine). So far, I've tried the following options but couldn't get it to work.

Added an Execute PowerShell task to store release variables into Environment variables:

```
$releaseVaraiables = Get-ChildItem Env: | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "ACL_*" } 
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=aclVariables]$releaseVaraiables"
```

Added an Execute PowerShell on remote machine task:

Here I can't read the Environment variables (maybe because this is remote machine task?)

```
Write-Verbose "problem reading $env:aclVariables" -Verbose
```

Then I tried passing the environment variable as an argument, but that didn't work either

```
param
(
    $RbacAccessTokenParams
)

$RbacAccessTokenParams.GetEnumerator() | % {$_.Name}
$RbacAccessTokenParams | % {
    Write-Verbose "variable is $_" -Verbose
    Write-Verbose "name is $_.Name" -Verbose
    Write-Verbose "value is $_.Value" -Verbose
}
```

This is how I passed as argument

```
-RbacAccessTokenParams $(aclVariables)
```

What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested your scenario on my side with TFS 2017.3.1, and it works when pass the environment variable as an argument. You can upgrade your TFS first and try again. Attach my steps for your reference:

1.[image]

2.[image]

3.

[image]

  4.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. however, you missed one key difference here. In my scenario, 'releaseVariables' is a collection of Environment variables starting with keyword 'acl' as you can see from my code in original post.

Comment: It seems we can't only one variable to pass a collection of Environment variables. You may consider copying the Environment variables to a document on the target machine and get it one by one.

Comment: Ah!. Thanks for letting me know of this limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Non-secret variables are already stored as environment variables; you do not need to do anything special to access them. You can access them with `$ENV:VariableName`. Periods are replaced with underscores. So `Foo.Bar` would be `$env:FOO_BAR`.

Secret variables should be passed in to the script that requires them.

However, this only applies **on the agent**. If you're using the `PowerShell On Target Machines` task to run a script, you need to pass the variables as arguments to the script. There is no way around this, unless you choose to use deployment groups.

Or, better yet, follow a configuration-as-code convention and store application-specific values in source controlled configuration files that your scripts read, so that you are not tightly coupled to your deployment orchestration platform.

Comment: So, can I pass an arg of type hashtable against "PowerShell On Target Machines" task parameters?